# Does the OnError hanler of the HandleError action filter handle exceptions that are already handled by try/catch blocks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am still confused about what types of errors the `HandleError` attribute/action filter handles.

For e.g. in the code below, assume that I have the `HandleError` filter defined as a global action filter for my MVC 4 application.

Will the exception I catch in my try catch block below even get to the `OnError` handler of the `HandleError` action filter?

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        new SomeBusinessLogicComponentInTheMVCProject().DoSomething();
        return View();
    }
}

public class SomeBusinessLogicComponentInTheMVCProject
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Will the HandleError filter's OnError 
            // handler catch this exception?
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your OnError() method in your filter wont get the exception since your catch block has  handled it already, unless the exception(or a new exception) was thrown again in the catch.

Both OnError in the ErrorHandelingFilter or the OnException method on Controller(the class your SomeController inheritants from) would only handle those unhandled exceptions from actions in controllers.